# How to display an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Well I'm a beginner and I would like to know how to display the array I made(It's an Integer array). I'm just trying to create a simple calculation program that accepts user input on which fighter they would like to pick, and how much money they would like to bet. Again, I'm just a beginner so no hate please.

```
public class Fighter {
private int health;
private int attack;
private int money;

int[] fighter={health,attack,money};

public Fighter(int h, int a, int m){

    health=h;
    attack=a;
    money=m;

}

public int[] getFighter(){

        return fighter;
}
```

}

*********END OF FIGHTER CLASS*******

```
import java.util.*;
public class FighterCreator {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Fighter newFighter=new Fighter((int)(Math.random() * 701),
                                   (int)(Math.random() * 39), 7000);
    System.out.print(newFighter.getFighter());
}
}
```

When I run the code it just displays hexadecimal, can you guys please explain it in a way a beginner would understand, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since each object has [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method, the default is displaying the *class name representation*, then adding `@` sign and then the *hashcode* of the array *instance*.

To view the *elements* inside the array, you can use [`Arrays#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourArray));
```

(See [its implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28int%5B%5D%29) for details to better understand what's going on)

---